# Ionic ion-view header behind ios status bar

Tags: iphone, ionic-framework

How do I avoid ionic header from getting behind ios status bar like this?

[image]

I created the header with following code:

```
<ion-view title="{{title}}" hide-nav-bar="false">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally the problem is solved.

in app.js

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
  if (window.cordova && $cordovaKeyboard) {
    $cordovaKeyboard.hideAccessoryBar(true);
  }
  if (window.StatusBar) {
    StatusBar.styleDefault();
  }
}
```

and, if that doesn't solve the problem yet. In index.html, cordova.js should be imported on the very last.

```
<head>
    ...

    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
</head>
```

This solve my problem.

Comment: it does not work on latest ionic version. Check the date.

Answer (score 14):

I have been stuck on the same problem for a long time and none of the above solutions worked for me. Finally, to get the status bar from overlapping on the app's view, I added the following `preference` to my `config.xml` file and viola:

```
  <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
  <preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#000000" />
  <preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="lightcontent" />
```

This ofcourse requires the plugin: `cordova-plugin-statusbar "StatusBar"`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Newb question alert. Where would StatusBar.overlaysWebView(false) be inserted?

Comment: I added the above preference options in my config.xml file which is at the root of your project.

Comment: I added the plugin: cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-statusbar then added  the preferences but still have overlap.  I'm only looking in ionic serve not on a device though.

Comment: Did you recompile or serve the app again for the changes to take effect?

Comment: Yes.  I ended up devising my own CSS-only solution, since this is only an iOS issue.

Comment: Thats good. If you can resolve through CSS, then it is a good solution.

Answer (score 11):

From: http://www.sitepoint.com/5-ionic-app-development-tips-tricks/

Ionic has specific classes to deal with this – platform-ios and platform-cordova. Ionic’s pre-built elements target those classes and add in 20px top margin to the buttons in your header to make up for these situations. To get my own custom elements to do the same, I follow the same pattern. For my .search-bar above, I add a margin if we’ve got a .platform-ios.platform-cordova:not(.fullscreen) body class. Example:

```
.platform-ios.platform-cordova:not(.fullscreen) .search-bar {
     margin-top: 20px;
}
```

This should be the correct answer.

Comment: To make the code more robust, use the variable that ionic provides: margin-top: $ios-statusbar-height;

Comment: i added this as global style but does not work. Probabily Ionic classes changed

Comment: @fikkatra how can I use this variable inside scss?

Answer (score 7):

The solution with `StatusBar.styleDefault();` did not work for me, but calling `StatusBar.overlaysWebView(false)` did the job.

First screenshot is UI of the app before calling `StatusBar.overlaysWebView(false)`, you can see that the iOS status bar is over the app and user cannot click the whole area of menu button:

[image: iOS status bar is over the app and user cannot click the whole area of menu button]

Now when I call `StatusBar.overlaysWebView(false)`, the iOS status bar is no longer over the menu button:

[image: iOS status bar is no longer over the menu button]

Comment: In which file did you call StatusBar.overlaysWebView(false) ?

Answer (score 3):

adding margin won't work exactly. It will only create an empty space at the bottom of your screen.

The fix is to make sure you have `viewport-fit = cover` in your app's meta tag.

Answer (score 2):

Try this for Ionic 5.x, just put index.html inside

`<meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />`

Answer (score 1):

This solved the problem for me. Add this CSS to `ion-toolbar`, it will automatically adjust.

```
&__toolbar {
  margin-top: calc(env(safe-area-inset-top));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is working for me with ionic 3 (3.7.1)
Open `App.scss` in `app` folder then add this code:

```
.platform-ios 
{
  page-home { // replaced by your page HERE
     top: 20px !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: This creates a small black stripe under the status bar.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick reminder,
If this issue only happens in some of the subpages, you probably used nav.push() inside a modal(this is depreciated).
To fix this issue, in your modal

```
import { App, ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';
```

```
 constructor(
      public viewCtrl: ViewController
      public app: App
    ) {}
```

replace push() with below

```
  //this.navCtrl.push(nextPage);
  this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
  this.appCtrl.getRootNav().push(nextPage);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a better option to do this. In AppModule.ts make change to `IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {statusbarPadding: true}),` and from app.component.ts remove or comment `statusBar.overlaysWebView(true);` it will fix your problem for IOS.

Answer (score 0):

Add following code in config.xml

```
<preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" /><br>
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" /><br>
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" /><br>

App.component.ts<br>
Inside constructor<br>
this.statusBar.overlaysWebView(false);<br>
this.statusBar.styleLightContent()
```

Answer (score 0):

@Ferdy-Fauzi's answer did the trick; however, since the index.html gets overwritten on every build here my usage of ionic hooks to apply the changes after every build.

Add hooks in your `ionic.config.json` file

```
{
  "name": "xxxx",
  "integrations": {
    "capacitor": {}
  },
  "type": "vue",
  "id": "xxxxx",
  "hooks": {
     "build:after": "./deploy/after-build.js"
   }
}
```

and then in your project folder (top level) create folder `deploy` with file `after-build.js` with following content:

```
var fs = require('fs')
module.exports = (ctx) => {
   const index = `${ctx.project.dir}/dist/index.html`;
   fs.readFile(index , 'utf8', (err, html) => {
       const meta = '<meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />';
      html = html.replace(/<meta name="viewport".*?">/, meta);
      fs.writeFile(index, html, 'utf8', err => err && console.log( err ));
   });
};
```